# What is the proper way to use static members of FontFamily and SystemFonts?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to set the font of a `TextBox` using, for example, `System.Drawing.FontFamily.GenericMonospace` and `System.Drawing.SystemFonts.IconTitleFont.SizeInPoints`.

When I use code like:

```
_TBTextBox.Font = new Font(System.Drawing.FontFamily.GenericMonospace, System.Drawing.SystemFonts.IconTitleFont.SizeInPoints);
```

[.Net Memory Profiler](http://memprofiler.com/) informs me that an instance of `System.Drawing.Font` and an instance of `System.Drawing.FontFamily` are both being garbage collected without being disposed.

Wrapping the font set in `using` blocks eliminates the disposal problem, but seems inefficient and like it should be unnecessary.

```
// No garbage-collection-without-disposal issues
using (Font iconTitleFont = System.Drawing.SystemFonts.IconTitleFont)
{
    using (FontFamily family = System.Drawing.FontFamily.GenericMonospace)
    {
         _TBTextBox.Font = new Font(family, iconTitleFont.SizeInPoints);
    }
}
```

Do all uses of the static members of these classes have to be first assigned to local variables that are themselves disposed? If so why?

Comment: It depends whether the property returns a new instance every time.

Comment: your last block of code would just end up using an already disposed Font (later, when it's actually used) so you most certainly don't want to do that.

Comment: if you want to use the _TBTextBox.Font move that to the outside of the using and this should fix your issue..

Comment: The SystemFonts.IconTitleFont property getter itself creates a font that it doesn't dispose.  You can't fix that.  It is not the end of the world as we know it, the next garbage collection cleans it up.  Use tooling like this only when you have a real problem.

Comment: @Servy What do you mean? The font set in _TBTextBox.Font will be disposed? This code runs as is (in a simplified example with only one form containing a single TextBox)

Comment: @csabol Presumably at some point something uses the `Font` that you've set there.  If it's used at any later point it will be after the end of the `using` statements, so the two fonts will already have been disposed.  If it actually works, the most likely answer is that these types don't actually do anything when disposed and that they just implement `IDisposable` because a parent type defined it in anticipation of some children needing to be disposed.

Comment: @Servy The value in `_TBTextBox.Font` will not be disposed, only `iconTitleFont` and `family` will. Since `_TBTextBox.Font` only has a dependency on `iconTitleFont.SizeInPoints`, which is a `float`, it is unlikely that disposal will have any effect. Apparently the constructor must be extracting some data from the passed `FontFamily` rather than keeping a copy of it or else we would be in trouble here?

Comment: @HansPassant `Font`s have unmanaged data (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) so not disposing of them could leak memory that the garbage collector won't catch.

Comment: Well, of course not, that would be rather disastrous.  The Font class has a finalizer.